# dojo 1.8 - Unable to update ComboBox every time there ia a change in select

Tags: dojo

Hi I have a select(3 options) and a ComboBox to be updated with new options each time select is changed. However, I am not able to update or refresh ComboBox each time the select is changed. It only works if the page is refreshed.

```
meter_Select.on('change', function()
{
console.debug("selected -> " + meter_Select.value);
switch(meter_Select.value)
{
case 'testdata1970_05': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response2});
break;
case 'testdata1970_10': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response3});
break;
case 'testdata2060_03': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response1});
}

var combx = new ComboBox({
store: memoStore2,
    searchAttr: "mfg_code"
    }, "node_cardSelect");
    combx.startup();
```

For further, you can checkout at jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/9tNhN/6/
Please advise.
Would appreciate your help, and thanks in advance
Clement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your browser JavaScript console, you'll see something like this:

> Uncaught Error: Tried to register widget with id==node_cardSelect but that id is already registered

That's because you are trying to recreate the ComboBox every time with the same ID. If the ComboBox already exists, you can either update the store and call startup again, or just destroy it and create a new one.

```
        var combx = registry.byId("node_cardSelect");
        if(combx) {
            combx.store = memoStore2;
        }
        else {
            combx = new ComboBox({
                store: memoStore2,
                searchAttr: "mfg_code"
            }, "node_cardSelect");
        }

        combx.startup();
```

Here's an updated jsfiddle with the fix above: http://jsfiddle.net/nhnDr/1/

Comment: it's odd. In jsfiddle, combx is not able to show the value displayed after one of the options is selected

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it appears to be working for me (Chrome)